# Multiple similar entities or use the same one in core data?

Tags: core-data

So I've got a Client entity that needs a relationship to a PhoneNumber entity to allow multiple phone numbers. And I've got an Employee entity that also needs a relationship to a PhoneNumber entity to allow multiple phone numbers. Should I create two separate PhoneNumber entities or can I somehow use the same entity for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a parent entity called `Person` for your `Client` and `Employee` entities. The `Person` entity would have a relationship to the `PhoneNumber` entity.

Inherited entities have the same attributes and relationships as their parent entity. Of course you can add attributes and relationships to the "child"-entities as well. I omitted that in the screenshot.

Something like this:

[image]

you can configure the parent entity in the core data inspector in the right side pane.